# Android fragment reyclerview in viewpager not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-tabs

I have a fragment, recyclerview, viewpager problem that I have been stuck on for a few weeks now.

I have four tabs each having fragments in each one and tabs 1 and 4 have recycler views. However, when I got back and forth, for some reason my list in the recycler view is initially empty until I click a button which calls updateUI():

```
  ...
  mResult = realmResults.get(0);

  for(int i = 0; i < mResult.getItems().size(); i++){
     mList.add(mResult.getItems.get(i));
  {

  if(mRecyclerView.getAdapter() == null) {
        mAdapter = new MultViewAdapter(mList);
        mSubjectRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

But when that is called, the list that shows up increases by one, when it should still be the same. Possibly creating another list on top of the original because everytime I go back and forth in the tabs, it just adds an extra item to the list by 1.

Also, on the logcat it shows the following error every time I visit that tab.

```
RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

From my understanding, after going to a tab 4 the fragment will be destroyed because of the method setOffscreenPageLimit, so when going back to tab1 it should call onCreateView which should then create a new adapter and show the list.
I don't understand how the list is initially empty. My onCreateView is:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_subject_list, container, false);
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    mSubjectRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.subject_recycler_view);

    mSubjectRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    updateUI();

    return view;
}
```

So the recyclerview should have a new adapter each time.

Thanks!

Comment: @Blackbelt Sorry I'll add more code in my updateUI. I have it to add items to the list right before creating a new adapter in the updateUI() method. But the initial deceleration is empty:   private List<Item> mList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: do you add items to `mList` before submitting `mList` to the Adapter?

Comment: Ok, i add the items to the list before the adapter in updateui

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it is before the adapter. See the first part of the edited code posted, in the for each loop.

Comment: set `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);` so that the fragment is not destroyed each time you switch between tab 1 and 4

Comment: Yea doing that will solve the issues, however I am hoping to not having to resort to that because my tabs 2-3 uses a lot of resources at startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opps, I forgot to call mList.clear() right before the for-each loop. Thanks all.